# Crosshair label over axis with JFreeChart

Tags: jfreechart

JFreeChart draws the crosshair label inside the chart area, but is it possible to draw it on the axis instead? It would look like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm not aware of any support for this; I usually go for a marker, annotation, attributed label or title; or a specialty (sub)chart: dial, meter, thermometer _etc_.

Comment: A related approach is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72370245/230513).